# Outlook 2007 Addin C# - Startup Path

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, clickonce, outlook-addin

I am using some Win32 dlls in an Outlook 2007 add-in.

So I added the dlls, with build action "Content" and copy to local directory.

To get the path to them, I would normally use:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "MyDll.dll");
```

When published by ClickOnce, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly not giving me the standard path to all my ClickOnce files.  My files are in *%appdata%..\Local\Apps\2.0*, but the assembly is in *%appdata%..\Local\assembly*.

Is there a better way to get the path to these dlls from within an Outlook add-in deployed by ClickOnce?

Comment: Also tried Application.StartupPath, but that gives me the path to Outlook's exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is giving me the correct path now:

```
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, "MyDll.dll");
```

I've had to use SetupInformation when parsing command-line arguments, and some debugging led me to this property.

I will post back if it gives me any trouble, as we will need to install on several machines and see what happens.

Comment: Are you using a set up project to deploy this? You can specify a folder in the file system and specify the paths directly.

Comment: It is ClickOnce, it says in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding them in as a reference?  I believe that the add-in should know the location if you put them in that way.  Just look at how it handles the Office Interops (and other references) when you add them in - no need to specify, just reference them in your code.

Comment: Those are .Net references.  You cannot do this with Win32 dlls.

Comment: Still a newbie on c# programming.  first thing that popped into my head.